# RecyclerView cells not saving for later

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here is my Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter mainAdapter;
private List<ToDoItem> toDoItems = new ArrayList<ToDoItem>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



    mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(toDoItems, R.layout.todoitem, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ToDoItem toDoItem = new ToDoItem();
            toDoItem.toDoItemName = "+";
            toDoItems.add(toDoItem);
            mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


}
```

The problem is that whenever I add a bunch of cells when I hit the FAB and then completely close the app and reopen the app, all of the cells are no longer there. How do I change my code to make it so that even when I completely close the app, the cells I added will still be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you aren't persisting your *toDoItems* anywhere, and the next time you open the app, you are starting anew.
You should save your state, and everytime you open the app, check if there is something saved, and if so  load it.
For more information refer to [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) guide on **Storage Options**

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What storage option would you suggest for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Based on your code, only the number of toDoItems matter, because you're always adding "+"value. In that case use SharedPreferences to store that number. If you actually want to save toDoItems with different values, then a database would be best. For databases, you don't have to use pure SQL, it's easier to use an ORM, such as ORM Lite, or DBFLOW etc.

Comment: I appreciate it, I think I have a good idea of where to go from here.